# Azure Batch Instance Sizes

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-batch

I'm running massive parallel jobs on Azure Batch now, works ok but to my regret I can't seem to use A0 instances. The jobs I run are very low in memory or disk usage, so I only want 'bare' cores ideally.

A1 instances are fine also, but the cost ~ 5 ct/hr while A0's cost ~1,5 ct/hr, and they would be enough.

So: how can I use A0's in Azure batch, and if not, I guess it would be (a lot) cheaper to run on Worker roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Batch supports all Azure VM sizes except STANDARD_A0 and those with premium storage (STANDARD_GS, STANDARD_DS, and STANDARD_DSV2 series).

see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-api-basics/ for more information.

The workerroles can indeed provide the most economical solution.

Comment: Googled for an hour for this but couldn't find it; tnx!

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of [Azure Batch Low Priority VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-low-pri-vms) the prices for certain types of VMs (assuming that your workload is amenable for preemption) are now far lower than either STANDARD_A0 or even a BASIC_A0 instance.

For example: pricing taken on 2017-05-15, a Low Priority STANDARD_A1_V2 instance in West Central US costs $0.007/hr compared to $0.02/hr for a STANDARD_A0. Not only do you get more performance, but you won't be on shared infra like the A0. You can view [Batch Low Priority Pricing here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/batch/).